# How to import the xml file in a GWT web project and pass it as a fileInputStream parameter() as the way for java project is failing

Tags: java, gwt, xml-import

In a Java Project in eclipse we can import a xml file by:File-->Import-->Xml and then we can
give the path of the folder containing xml file.So the entire folder gets imported and we can
pass the xml as `FileInputStream(new File("foldername/xmlfilename.xml"))`;

How can we import an xml file in a GWT project in eclipse and pass it as parameter to 
`FileInputStream(())`.Please help as it cannot be done like it is done for Java Project.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use FileInputStream and there are no alternate File apis emulated in GWT.

You can process it on server side and then send it over "JSON" , XML or Plain Text "Response" to GWT client code.

You can reference about pulling this data to client under **Processing the response** section in https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication

If You want to push XML to client side - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsXML